# Redirect https requests to different port

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have multiple websites on one Magento install.  Three of these sites have different SSL certificates.  SNI is not an option so we decided to use different ports to handle the requests.

In Virtual Hosts config, each site that uses SSL is assigned a different port.

"https://domain1.com" -> Standard 443

"https://domain2.com:444"

"https://domain3.com:445"

These requests work fine if you go to them directly.  Magento handles all its requests properly.

Here is the rub:

If you go to "https://domain2.com" without the port number you trigger the Virtual Host Configuration for domain1.com.

I need a way to catch all requests to https://domain2.com and redirect them to https://domain2.com:444.

There has to be a way to do this with mod_rewrite or mod_proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using mod_rewrite, but the problem here is that your certificate won't be for domain2.com and the browser is going to complain (unless these are actually subdomains and you have a wildcard certificate)

Add these rules to the domain1 config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com:444/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain3.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain3.com:445/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Tried that. For one thing it pushes the whole site into 444 and no links work unless I reset Magento to display the whole site behind that port.  That would play hell with SEO.  

Maybe there is another way to go about this.  Is there a way to just bounce these requests back to http://domain2.com?

Comment: Ah, if you don't want it to redirect, try replacing the `[R=301]` to `[P]`?